# Why 'New Kotlin Class/File' window not responding to keyboard when making a new Kotlin class in android?

Tags: android-studio

**Error message shown in terminal inside android studio is**

*ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/spectrwm/libswmhack.so.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.*

Once I make a right click on com.example.myapplication> new > Kotlin class/file, a window appears that asks for name of the class. That 'New Kotlin Class/File' window does not take any input from the keyboard. I even tried it in xfce Desktop Environment, but faced same problem.

I'm running android on Debian 11 with spectr window manager.  My android studio is ran via flatpak. I have Kotlin plugin installed. The keyboard also works fine in all other aspects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an solution but a workaround.

The mouse still works in that window. Write the name of the class or file somewhere else, copy it to the clipboard control+shift+c. Then paste it in the name field with middle mouse button click. Then double click on the type of file you want to create.